# How to modify outside variable from inside an event handler in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, event-handling

I have a button with a click event listener

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
let show = false;
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     e.stopPropagation();
     show = !show;
     console.log("show from inside:", show)
});
console.log("show from outside:", show) // => is always equal to false
```

But this line above still shows the same value for variable `show` as initialized.

How can i modify `show` variable from inside like this line `show = !show` and get that modification from outside at this line `console.log("show from outside:", show)` ?

Comment: Why would the outside `show` change? It runs before the click handler does.

Comment: @evolutionxbox basically that's the behavior i want: modify an outside variable from inside an event handler.

Comment: Make another event listener that runs after the click, log the value of `show` and you will see that it has changed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox please provide a full answer below so i can try it.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the element but did not append it to body/parent node. You need to add the following line to your code.

```
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

If you need to get the modified `show` value, you can write a function to return the value of `show` and use it whereever you want.

Final Code:

```
let button = document.createElement('button');
document.body.appendChild(button);

let show = false;
function getShow() { return show; } // => returns the latest value of show

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
     e.stopPropagation();
     show = !show;
     console.log("show from inside:", getShow());
});
console.log("show from outside:", getShow()); // => Keep in mind that this line will run before the event handler does and only for once.
```

Hope this helps!